# searchpath for prereqisites, like vpath, but only for some pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to build several executables in one `make` instance, as suggested by 
[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf).
The arguments of that paper apply to my project because some of my source files are generated, and go into multiple executables.

The object files for each of these executables go into separate directories, because they are compiled with different preprocessor flags.

How can I specify separate `vpath` settings for each of these executables, so that source files with duplicate filenames in separate directories go into the executables where I want them to go?

Setting `vpath` before the rules to build the object files for one executable, and erasing it afterwards (by not giving any directories) doesn't have the desired effect. Apparently, the last setting is used for all the rules.

Solutions I see currently:

- Rename source filenames to use unique names so that I can use a global `vpath` setting
- Instead of `vpath`, use separate rules for each source directory, with the source directory in the prerequisite pattern (*)
- Recursive make, with separate `vpath` settings in each `make` instance, and somehow deal with the resulting trouble.
- Use something different than `make`.

Is there a better solution, or which one of the above would you prefer?

(*) The solution with separate rules looks like this:

```
build/$(PROGRAM)/%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_RECIPE)

build/$(PROGRAM)/%.o: $($(PROGRAM)_SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE_RECIPE)
```

Ok for my current project, but would become ugly fast, if there where more than one directory different in the source paths of the executables

**Edit:** Test for suggestion of @Etan, which shows that `$^` is empty, when the prerequisites appear only in pattern rules (`y/y.c`) - this only works if each dependency is given directly, as for `x/x.c`.

```
.PHONY: all

all: build/x.o build/y.o

build/x.o: x/x.c
# the following rule is ignored:
build/%.o: y/%.c
# because there is a matching pattern rule with a recipe:
build/%.o:
    @echo \"$@\" from \"$^\"
    @touch $@
```

The files `x/x.c`,  `y/y.c` and the directory `build` exist.

output:

```
"build/x.o" from "x/x.c"
"build/y.o" from ""
```

Tested with `GNU Make 3.82.90`

Comment: I think the best solution here is likely to be explicitly constructed prerequisite pairs mapping input to output. But you don't need a recipe for each pair just the prerequisite addition. You just need the recipe once for the output pattern. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27677246/258523) for an example of this model (the second `eval` solution).

Comment: @Etan: With your solution, where the rule with the recipe has no prerequisite pattern, you can't use `$^` in the recipe (I tried and got an empty string). So how do you tell the compiler in which directory to find the source file?

Comment: Are you sure you generated your rules correctly? Because that should work just fine. A static pattern rule for the output files might work a bit more safely but may not be necessary. See https://gist.github.com/deryni/10d25d020b2232867bd7

Comment: @Etan: This only works if each dependency is given directly, see the test I appended to the question. Using a static pattern rule doesn't improve anything, here.

Comment: Fair enough. So you would need the `$(COMPILE_RECIPE)` for each, oh well. That is, assuming you use pattern rules for anything other than the final target which I was not suggesting. I was suggesting all literal pairs as in my gist (which either needs the static pattern version or `-r` to avoid the built-in rules).

Answer (score 3):

First, it's never correct to use VPATH or vpath to find derived files (files that are built by make)... that includes "source files that are generated" (if they are generated by make, and not before make is invoked somehow).  VPATH/vpath can only be used to find source files (files that are not built by make).  See [How not to use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) for more information.

Second, vpath is a global setting, not a per-target setting.  Whenever make wants to find a prerequisite and that prerequisite doesn't exist "normally", make will use the vpath settings to find it.  There's no facility in vpath to say "for this target use these vpath settings, for that target use those".  In an ideal world, you would be able to set VPATH as a target-specific variable but this doesn't work.

There are various ways to generate prerequisites based on a target: you might find some of the suggestions on [metaprogramming in make](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/) helpful.

Lastly, the makefile example you give regarding `$^` is not correct:

```
# the following rule is ignored:
build/%.o: y/%.c
# because there is a matching pattern rule with a recipe:
build/%.o:
        @echo \"$@\" from \"$^\"
        @touch $@
```

You cannot specify a pattern rule without any recipe and have it "add" prerequisite patterns to some other existing pattern rule.  It works for explicit rules, to add more prerequisites to a target, but specifying a pattern rule with no recipe simply [deletes the pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

So, `$^` is empty for `build/y.o` because there are no prerequisites defined in the pattern rule and you've not defined any explicit prerequisites for `build/y.o` like you did for `build/x.o`.

ETA: The reference to metaprogramming was to suggest that you can use it to make your second option, which is the one I would use, be less typing and easier maintenance.  Pick the method you prefer and auto-generate the various pattern rules.  This might be termed a "fifth option".

Other than that any of the four you suggest are fine, and there isn't another option you're missing that I'm aware of.

Comment: Generated files: This is just the reason why I don't want recursive make. I don't need VPATH for these.

Comment: You cannot specify a pattern rule without any recipe and have it "add" prerequisite patterns to some other existing pattern rule: Yes, I realized this, too, after I tried, and I tried to explain why one idea from the comments doesn't work for me, because of that. Thanks for the background explanation.

Comment: metaprogramming: Interesting page, thanks. But didn't find the answer to my question there, yet.